# Conditional Select with mysql and PHP for a calendar app

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently programming a calendar with php and mysql and im stuck with some functionality while selecting all events i want to display. I implemented the possibilty to repeat an event. Therefore i set a timestamp from which the event starts and a timestamp to determine when the event ends. Furthermore i got some integer values which represent the rythm in which the event is repeated.
Then i fetch the events based on a timestamp which is send with a request.

I now want to enable the user to shift events from the weekend to the Friday before the weekend or the monday after the weekend. For example:

```
From: 1450306800 (today) 
until: 0 (infinite)
rythm : 1 (-> every month)
jump:2 (-> on every 2nd day / month)
weekends : 3 (-> shift to next monday)

-> January 2nd 2016 is a saturday and i want to display that event on the next monday.
```

currently my select looks something like this: (:day -> timestamp from request, :d -> day of month from :day, :weekday -> day of the week from :day)

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE repeat_from <= :day 
  AND ((repeat_until >= :day) OR (repeat_until = 0))
  AND CASE weekends
    WHEN 0 THEN (:weekday BETWEEN 1 AND 7)
    WHEN 1 THEN (:weekday < 6)
    WHEN 2 THEN ??
    WHEN 3 THEN ??
  AND CASE rythm 
    WHEN 1 THEN (:d - DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(repeat_from))) / (jump + 1) = CEIL ((:d - DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(repeat_from))) / (jump + 1)) ... [all the other cases]
```

How do i check if the event would have been displayed on saturday or sunday before/after within the select? The only way i can think of is to more or less repeat the whole select from the "...AND CASE rythm..." part which is quite alot.
Or would the best way be, to fetch the event on every monday/friday anyway if it shifts and then check with a php function if the event would have been displayed on saturday or sunday ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do all the calculations and matching on the PHP back-end? With that much cases and clauses in your MySQL query you'll probably get yourself a really slow execution.

Select all Events by your major criteria. In your case that would probably be:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    events 
WHERE 
    repeat_from <= :day AND
    (
        (repeat_until >= :day) OR 
        (repeat_until = 0)
    )
```

Then just loop through all fetched rows and apply the [built-in](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) date() method - much faster and flexible:

```
# you can match the week number of different dates 
$currentWeekNumber = date('W');
$specificDayWeekNumber = date('W', strtotime($specificDate));

# or match the day number
$currentDayNumber = date('N');
$specificDayNumber = date('N', strtotime($specificDate));
```

The `date()` method is super flexible and will allow you to check if certain Event date is within the weekend or not, so you can manipulate it further.

If you provide some further explanations and/or examples, I'll try to be more specific with the solution. Cheers.

Comment: isnt selecting with sql faster than just fetching everything and then dumping half of it with php afterwards ? Thats basically the only reason im trying to fit it in the select statement and not into a filtering function within php.

Comment: @Lapskaus Generally yes, but the date functions (as many other built-in MySQL functions) take additional time and resources to make the necessary calculations. You could actually compare the response time for both and see which one works better for you. But in the original query not only date functions are used, but conditions are also in place, which add to the delay.